# Plotting the Full width at half maximum as a function of a parameter

Tags: numerical-integration, piecewise, numerical-value

I have this function and I want to plot the FWHM of it as a function of the parameter "a", defined between 0 and 10. It should look like the picture attached. I also put the original equation in case I wrote something wrong. Can this be done in a simple manner?

[image: April 1987 / Vol. 12, No. 4 / OPTICS LETTERS]

```
h[ν_] := 2 BesselJ[1, ν]/ν

G[ν_] := 
 Piecewise[{{(Abs[h[ν]]^2)*(2*Pi*
        NIntegrate[(Abs[h[t]]^2)*t, {t, 0, a - ν}] + 
       2*NIntegrate[(Abs[h[t]]^2)*t*
          ArcCos[((t^2 + ν^2 - a)/(2*t*ν))]^2, {t, 
          a - ν, ν + a}]), ν < 
     a}, {(Abs[h[ν]]^2)*(2*
       NIntegrate[(Abs[h[t]]^2)*t*
         ArcCos[((t^2 + ν^2 - a)/(2*t*ν))]^2, {t, ν - 
          a, ν + a}]), ν > a}}]
```

Comment: What is v1/2 in the plot? I don't seem to find a value where this particular plot appears. Also: the first integral in the first line is analytically solvable by mathematica.

Comment: v1/2 is the value of v at which the intensity falls to one half of its value at v=0, as a function of "a" or v_p. It is half of the FWHM. I used Nintegrate to speed the calculations.